# ASIHTTPRequest crashing in performInvocation

Tags: objective-c, ios4, asihttprequest

I'm getting a crash in ASIHTTPRequest on the performInvocation: method.

The stack is:

```
ASIHTTPRequest performInvocation:onTarget:releasingObject: 1877
ASIHTTPRequest performSelector:onTarget:withObject:amount:callerToRetain: 1870
ASIHTTPRequest updateProgressIndicator:withProgress:ofTotal: 1903
ASINetworkQueue request:didReceiveBytes: 240
ASIHTTPRequest performInvocation:onTarget:releasingObject: 1877
```

This is the method where the crash happens:

```
+ (void)performInvocation:(NSInvocation *)invocation onTarget:(id *)target releasingObject:(id)objectToRelease
{
  if (*target && [*target respondsToSelector:[invocation selector]]) {
    [invocation invokeWithTarget:*target];
  }
    CFRelease(invocation);
    if (objectToRelease) {
        CFRelease(objectToRelease);
    }
}
```

I believe it to be happening on the invokeWithTarget call.

This happens rarely, but in a large-scale deployment it's happening a lot.

Searching around, I found a vague reference to adding:

[cbInvocation retainArguments];

back in performSelector:... right before the [cbInvocation performSelectorOnMainThread:...] call.  But it hardly seemed authoritative, and I'm not certain I understan what's going on there enough to make and/or trust that sort of change.  I cannot reproduce the problem locally, but I get a large number of crash reports with this stack trace from the field.

This on iOS code, by the way.

Anyone have an idea what this might be?

Answer (score 1):

Your downloadProgressDelegate has been freed, without removing it from ASIHTTPRequest's downloadProgressDelegate first.

In the dealloc implementation for your download progress delegate, call:

```
[request setDownloadProgressDelegate:nil];
```