# ASIHTTPRequest and EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, asihttprequest, exc-bad-access

Actually the problem is on screen below. It appears, when the request is started:

[image]

The problem is only on iOS 5.0 and above. On iOS 4.3 all seems to be ok. What can it be?

**UPD:** Original [image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uhmkb.png)

Comment: nothing is visible in screen shot, can you post some code where it is crashing?

Comment: yeah that screenshot is awful

Comment: I am not sure, but it seems that the request's target was deallocated and then you tried to access it. If it is the case and you want to solve it rapidly (but uglily), set the request's delegate property as retain instead of assign.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASIHTTPRequest crashing in performInvocation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534294/asihttprequest-crashing-in-performinvocation)

Comment: **Ricard Pérez del Campo**, this didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

As a wild guess, without seeing any of the relevant code, I would say that you didn't call -clearDelegatesAndCancel.

From http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

```
// Ddealloc method for our controller
- (void)dealloc
{
   [request clearDelegatesAndCancel];
   [request release];
   ...
   [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You break the Cocoa memory management rules in that method by releasing objects you do not own.  I think you are over releasing the invocation and you were just getting lucky in older versions of the framework.

Also, why do you use CFRelease on an NSInvocation?  I don't think it's toll free bridged to any CF object.

Also, NSInvocation does not retain its arguments.  Make sure they haven't been released.

Comment: The code is part of ASIHTTPRequest (not sure if asker has changed anything), but the invocation is released the correct number of times. (Not sure about the CFRelease vs NSInvocation thing.) The asker has almost certainly made error that leaves ASIHTTPRequest's delegate set to an object that has been released.

Comment: @JosephH: If that piece of code is part of ASIHTTPRequest, it's a good argument not to use that code.  The writers don't understand the memory management rules.